# Wicket authentication error following example

Tags: java, authentication, wicket

I am learning wicket and trying to implement Authentication based on the flowing strategy

[Example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/authentication3/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.authentication3.HomePage)

I created `MyAuthenticatedWebApplication` class and also `MyAuthenticatedWebSession` with all other components, but as soon as I am trying to go to `MySignInPage`, I get this error.

**Last cause: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession cannot be cast to org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession
WicketMessage: Error attaching this container for rendering: [Page class = com.myapp.wicket.SignInPage, id = 3, render count = 1]**

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you have this in your web application class? `protected Class<? extends AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() { return MyAuthenticatedWebSession.class;  }`

Comment: Yes I have this  in my  application class,  can the problem be because my  application class in different folder

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `getWebSessionClass()` and see whether it is called/used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Override
protected Class<? extends AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession > getWebSessionClass() {
    return BasicAuthenticationSession.class;
}
```

try to use

```
@Override
protected Class<? extends AuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() {
    return BasicAuthenticationSession.class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
When you define a class that extends `AuthenticatedWebApplication`, you don't have any method:

```
protected Class<? extends AuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() {
    return BasicAuthenticationSession.class; }
```

So you cannot override that method.

**Background**:
I had the same problem, but the solutions above don't work.